# is Rohingya Genocide related to their religion?

Tags: shia-sunni, helping

I am sure that you've heard these shocking news about **Rohingya Crisis**. And we know that they are our Muslim brothers and sisters.

My question is that what branch of Islam do they belong to? And is it right to help and defend them without regarding of what branch they are?

We know that defending the rights of oppressed people is one of the main characteristics of Muslims.

Thanks

Comment: Helping the oppressed - no matter their religion - is part of  Islam.

Comment: @FarewellStackExchange Both. This idea of helping a drowning man only after knowing what their faith is, for example, is nonsensical and not part of the Islamic doctrine.

Comment: They're most likely to be Sunni.

Comment: The (off-topic [politics]) question in the title and the questions in the body (one is off-topic [opinion-based]; the other's answer is listed on the Wikipedia pages [Rohingya people](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rohingya_people) and [Islam in Myanmar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islam_in_Myanmar)) are distinct.  [Which question](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2965/why-we-should-avoid-asking-multi-question-questions) do you want answered?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As reported by different sources they are most likely Sunni Muslims, but this does not matter; this is a humanitarian disaster.

Shame on world organizations